# Does each object in the design play a conceptual role described in a domain model?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Eric Evan's DDD book, pg. 49:

> Setting aside purely technical issues, each object in the design plays
>   a conceptual role described in domain model.

I think what author is saying is that all objects in the design ( besides predefined types such as `int`, `string` ... ) also exist as concepts in the domain. Wouldn't such assumption be wrong, since I would assume there may be objects in the design that don't exist in a domain model, but are instead used to **help** describe a domain object or implement its behavior?

thanks

Comment: I think the important bit is probably the 'conceptual role'.  So even though something in the design doesn't end up in the domain model as a real artifact its intention is somehow contained in the domain model.

Comment: In addition to what Eben Roux said, note that the statement itself starts out with `Setting aside purely technical issues`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think whatever you need as help to describe a domain object or implement behavior would be a technical issue, which the author said to set aside.

Can you give an example of an object that is part of the domain design but is not a technical form of help and does not play a conceptual role in the domain model? If you can I would probably argue that it  should not be part of the domain's design.